# Mongo Group Query using the Ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I've got a working Mongo query that I need to translate into Ruby:

```
var reducer = function(current, result){
    result.loginsCount++;
    result.lastLoginTs = Math.max(result.lastLoginTs, current.timeStamp);
}

var finalizer = function(result){
    result.lastLoginDate = new Date(result.lastLoginTs).toISOString().split('T')[0];
}

db.audit_log.group({
     key : {user : true},   
     cond : {events : { $elemMatch : { action : 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'}}},
     initial : {lastLoginTs : -1, loginsCount : 0},
     reduce : reducer,
     finalize : finalizer
})
```

I'm hitting several sticking points getting this to work in Ruby. I'm not really all that familiar with Mongo, and I'm not sure what to pass as arguments to the method calls. This is my best guess, after connecting to the database and a collection called audit_log:

```
audit_log.group({
     "key" => {"user" => "true"},   
     "cond" => {"events" => { "$elemMatch" => { "action" => "LOGIN_SUCCESS"}}},
     "initial" => {"lastLoginTs" => -1, "loginsCount" => 0},
     "reduce" => "function(current, result){result.loginsCount += 1}",
     "finalize" => "function(result){ result.lastLoginDate = new Date(result.lastLoginTs).toISOString().split('T')[0]; }
})
```

Or something like that. I've tried using a simpler aggregate operation using the Mongo docs, but I couldn't get that working, either. I was only able to get really simple queries to return results. Are those keys (key, cond, initial, etc.) even necessary, or is that only for JavaScript?

Comment: I found this reference on Github: it's a Ruby-Mongo Koans tdd tutorial, and there's an example of the group() function.

https://github.com/chicagoruby/MongoDB_Koans/blob/master/koans/about_groups.rb

So the reduce and finalize methods are passed to Mongo as strings that contain JavaScript functions. Here's an example from the tutorial: 

 `@zips.group(
    [:city],
    {},
    { 'zsum' => 0, 'zc' => 0, 'avg_pop' => 0 }, 
    'function(doc,out) { out.zsum += doc.population; out.zc += 1; }',  
    'function(out){ out.avg_pop = out.zsum / out.zc}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the function finally took shape using the 1.10.0 Mongo gem:

```
@db.collection("audit_log").group(
  [:user, :events],
  {'events' => { '$elemMatch' => { 'action' => 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' }}},
  { 'lastLoginTs' => -1, 'loginsCount' => 0 },
  "function(current, result){ result.loginsCount++; result.lastLoginTs = Math.max(result.lastLoginTs, current.timeStamp);}",
  "function(result){ result.lastLoginDate = new Date(result.lastLoginTs).toISOString().split('T')[0];}"
)
```

With the Mongo Driver, you leave off the keys: "key", "cond", "initial", "reduce", "finalize" and simply pass in the respective values.

I've linked to two approaches taken by other SO users [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723547/how-to-use-mongodb-ruby-driver-to-do-a-group-group-by) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127374/mongodb-group-using-ruby-driver).